# Css transform in another transformed element

Tags: css, css-transforms, translate3d

I am making some 3D translated card , which has image and title on it,
the whole card has `transform: rotateX(Xdeg) rotateY(Ydeg)` , and working correctly with `mouseover` and `mousemove`.

The problem occurred when I want to add `translate3d` to `title` or `button` on the card , when mouse enter on card , `translate3d` will not work !

I use `transform` in another `transformed` element before, but it seems did not work when it applies on inline element `style` attribute(!), as I use js to produce inline `transform` style on `.card-beautiful`

```js
 // https://css-tricks.com/animate-a-container-on-mouse-over-using-perspective-and-transform/


(function() {
  // Init
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
      inner = document.querySelector(".beatiful-card");

  // Mouse
  var mouse = {
    _x: 0,
    _y: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    updatePosition: function(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
      this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
    },
    setOrigin: function(e) {
      this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
      this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
    },
    show: function() {
      return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
  };

  // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
  mouse.setOrigin(container);

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var counter = 0;
  var refreshRate = 10;
  var isTimeToUpdate = function() {
    return counter++ % refreshRate === 0;
  };

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var onMouseEnterHandler = function(event) {
    update(event);
  };

  var onMouseLeaveHandler = function() {
    inner.style = "";
  };

  var onMouseMoveHandler = function(event) {
    if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
      update(event);
    }
  };

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var update = function(event) {
    mouse.updatePosition(event);
    updateTransformStyle(
      (mouse.y / inner.offsetHeight / 2).toFixed(2),
      (mouse.x / inner.offsetWidth / 2).toFixed(2)
    );
  };

  var updateTransformStyle = function(x, y) {
    var style = "rotateX(" + x + "deg) rotateY(" + y + "deg) perspective(1.1px)";
    inner.style.transform = style;
    inner.style.webkitTransform = style;
    inner.style.mozTranform = style;
    inner.style.msTransform = style;
    inner.style.oTransform = style;
  };

  //--------------------------------------------------------

  container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
  container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
  container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
})();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  perspective: 25px;
}

.beatiful-card {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 35px -14px rgba(111, 208, 50, 0.58);
}
.beatiful-card:after, .beatiful-card:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: #b8bd8d4f;
  z-index: -3;
  height: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}
.beatiful-card:after {
  background: rgba(184, 189, 141, 0.25);
  height: 21px;
  bottom: -22px;
  right: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
.beatiful-card .images {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.beatiful-card .images img {
  width: 100%;
  filter: sepia(40%);
  height: 100%;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart svg {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  left: 83%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .title {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, -webkit-filter 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, filter 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, filter 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, -webkit-filter 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 11px 12px 24px;
  background: #978ed3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", tahoma, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 14px -4px rgba(54, 55, 149, 0.42);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 17px;
  top: 4px;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton:hover {
  background: #8378ca;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton:hover i {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton i {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font;
  padding: 9px 10px 8px 10px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
  top: -7px;
  right: -6px;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart p {
  height: 98px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart p:after {
  content: "";
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="beatiful-card">
    <div class="images"><img class="mainImage" src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/832/832/jbs96kw0/carpet-rug/v/3/f/carpetblu-03-supreme-home-collective-original-imaewgneqxtsvgfr.jpeg?q=70"/></div>
    <div class="holderPart">
      <h3 class="title">MyCode</h3>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#fff;"></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="callToActionButton">Hi , Jeffreson<i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code on 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jafar-rezaei/pen/ExYmygw?editors=0100). [sass and pug]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks , I'll update question

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` and remove the perspective you are adding at the end of the dynamic transform. It's useless since it's at the end.

The perspective defined in the container is already doing the job.

```js
// https://css-tricks.com/animate-a-container-on-mouse-over-using-perspective-and-transform/


(function() {
  // Init
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
      inner = document.querySelector(".beatiful-card");

  // Mouse
  var mouse = {
    _x: 0,
    _y: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    updatePosition: function(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
      this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
    },
    setOrigin: function(e) {
      this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
      this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
    },
    show: function() {
      return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
  };

  // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
  mouse.setOrigin(container);

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var counter = 0;
  var refreshRate = 10;
  var isTimeToUpdate = function() {
    return counter++ % refreshRate === 0;
  };

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var onMouseEnterHandler = function(event) {
    update(event);
  };

  var onMouseLeaveHandler = function() {
    inner.style = "";
  };

  var onMouseMoveHandler = function(event) {
    if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
      update(event);
    }
  };

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var update = function(event) {
    mouse.updatePosition(event);
    updateTransformStyle(
      (mouse.y / inner.offsetHeight / 2).toFixed(2),
      (mouse.x / inner.offsetWidth / 2).toFixed(2)
    );
  };

  var updateTransformStyle = function(x, y) {
    var style = "rotateX(" + x + "deg) rotateY(" + y + "deg) ";
    inner.style.transform = style;
    inner.style.webkitTransform = style;
    inner.style.mozTranform = style;
    inner.style.msTransform = style;
    inner.style.oTransform = style;
  };

  //--------------------------------------------------------

  container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
  container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
  container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
})();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  perspective: 25px;
}

.beatiful-card {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 35px -14px rgba(111, 208, 50, 0.58);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.beatiful-card:after, .beatiful-card:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: #b8bd8d4f;
  z-index: -3;
  height: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}
.beatiful-card:after {
  background: rgba(184, 189, 141, 0.25);
  height: 21px;
  bottom: -22px;
  right: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
.beatiful-card .images {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.beatiful-card .images img {
  width: 100%;
  filter: sepia(40%);
  height: 100%;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart svg {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  left: 83%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .title {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, -webkit-filter 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, filter 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, filter 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, -webkit-filter 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 11px 12px 24px;
  background: #978ed3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", tahoma, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 14px -4px rgba(54, 55, 149, 0.42);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 17px;
  top: 4px;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton:hover {
  background: #8378ca;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton:hover i {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart .callToActionButton i {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font;
  padding: 9px 10px 8px 10px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
  top: -7px;
  right: -6px;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart p {
  height: 98px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.beatiful-card .holderPart p:after {
  content: "";
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="beatiful-card">
    <div class="images"><img class="mainImage" src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/832/832/jbs96kw0/carpet-rug/v/3/f/carpetblu-03-supreme-home-collective-original-imaewgneqxtsvgfr.jpeg?q=70"/></div>
    <div class="holderPart">
      <h3 class="title">MyCode</h3>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#fff;"></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="callToActionButton">Hi , Jeffreson<i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```